# getting selected option using php DOMXPath

Tags: php, xpath, domdocument

i am using curl and trying to get the selected items from a select list using DOMXPath
I am close, i can get the selects and their options , just can not figure out how to tell if one is selected.

so here is my code so far. i can get the select name and all the option text and values

```
$newDom = new domDocument;
$newDom->loadHTML($result);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($newDom);
$values = $xpath->evaluate("/html/body//select");
for ($cnt = 0; $cnt < $values->length; $cnt++) {
       $value = $values->item($cnt);
       $name = $value->getAttribute('name');
       $options = $xpath->query("*/select[@name='".$name."']/option");
       foreach ($options as $option) {
           $optionValue = $option->getAttribute('value');
           $optionContent = $option->nodeValue;
       }
}


So i replaced

$options = $xpath->query("*/select[@name='".$name."']/option");
```

with

```
$options = $xpath->query("*/select[@name='".$name."']/option[@selected='selected']");
```

And now the $options is empty

the html looks like

```
<select name=inc_paytype>
<option value="0">None<option value="1">Cash/Check<option value="2" selected>Credit<option value="3">ECash<option value="4">EFT<option value="5">Credit once, then cash/check
 </select>
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: If the attribute is specified, you should be able to get it from `if ($option->getAttribute('selected') == 'selected')` But this is only of use for the default selected option in the markup you loaded into DOMDocument.

Comment: And the xpath should look like `*/select[@name='".$name."']/option[@selected='selected']`

Comment: I updated the original with more questions

Comment: I don't know how DOMDocument will respond if `selected` is not an XHTML style attribute `selected='selected'`

Comment: so is  there anyway to get the string or html from option tag and manually look for selected?

Answer (score 1):

i found the answer. Not perfect but works.

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($newDom);
$options = $xpath->query('/html/body//select');
foreach ($options as $option) {
       $name =$option->getAttribute('name');
       $children = $option->childNodes;
       foreach ($children as $child) {
            $tmp_doc = new DOMDocument();
            $tmp_doc->appendChild($tmp_doc->importNode($child,true));       
            if ( strstr( $tmp_doc->saveHTML() , "selected" ) ){
                 $optionValue = $child->getAttribute('value');
                 $optionContent = $child->nodeValue;
            }
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace "selected" with selected="selected" in the HTML file and then

```
$options = $xpath->query("//select[@name='".$name."']/option[@selected='selected']/@value");
```

This work for me.